# How to access to the photo gallery in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm facing an issue using ***ionic creator***, how can I upload an image from the phone gallery ?

**What I tried (most relevant tries)** :

- followed this tutorial  : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-user-ngcordova-with-ionic-creator/68619/2 to set the environnement with "ionic-native.min.js".

> *=> Get : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (*
>   *ionic.bundle.js:13443 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:*
>   *Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.*

- Tried to use "imagepicker" (without the warranty that I really have installed the plugin in my environnement, because in the creator I can't install sources from the web. So, crossed fingers and hope "ionic-native.min.js" provides it.)  : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker/
  => still not working.
- An finally I tried this : http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-native-accessing-ios-photos-and-android-gallery-part-2/
  => For the exact same result : white screen and errors.

I'm testing the app with both the web browser emulator (which I know sometimes doesn't work with cordova functions) and the ionic creator app on iphone. I'm sure someone have already faced and succeed this problem, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is adding cordova-plugin-camera to your project, it should works like a charm (Ionic 2.x) :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```